# Outlook.. How can I filter mails on conversation IDs?

Tags: outlook-addin

public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Search AdvancedSearch (string Scope, object Filter, object SearchSubFolders, object Tag)

Using above function of search, can I use filter on ConversationId without using filter on subjects?
Or can I get conversation ID of mails  from the results of advanceSerach? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Try to search on `PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC` (DASL property name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0070001F`).